# Spring MVC with AngularJS a good combination?

Tags: angularjs, spring-mvc

I had now two little projects with Spring MVC, Thymleaf, HTML, Bootstrap and vanilla JS/JQuery.

So I far I don't have much skills with AngularJS.

So I am curious about your oppinion if it makes sense to try to build up another project with Spring MVC and AngularJS combined or if these two doesn't fit that well together?

Ty

Comment: Try Vue.js instead of Angular. Its IMHO a far better way of doing FE MVC and its simply very elegant. We have Spring REST combined with Vue.js and ECMA and it works pretty well.

Comment: if you are really decoupling your app, I will go with Spring boot to develop API and use angular 2+, which is very easy for OOP developer.

Comment: Hmm, two opinions so far. This question off-topic because it is primarily opinion-based.
Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My Recommendation would be Spring boot + Angular as this is the combination of two best frameworks available in the market.

Please have a look at [JHIPSTER](https://www.jhipster.tech/) as it is project generating tool to create awesome project with so many already built in functionality and wide community support.

Answer (score 0):

AngularJS is one thing. Is a front end framework.
Spring MVC is another thing. Is a back end framework.
Then everything is good with AngularJS. And everything is good with Spring MVC.
AngularJS is old. Try to get a Angular4 experience for example. My opinion.